# Pivot Table.js - Filtrar valor pré definido

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou implementando na minha página uma pivot table semelhante a essa:

https://jsfiddle.net/nicolaskruchten/w86bgq9o/

Tenho a seguinte dúvida.

Considerando que os valores da Pivot Table campo **sex** vem como default marcados, no caso **Female** e **Male**.

Como faço para definir um valor padrão a ser marcado como filtro para o campo **sex**, no caso o primeiro item da lista de opções **(Female)**?

*Obs: Tentei inserir as imagens do link, no entanto, o stackoverflow mostra como formato proibido para upload*

html:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

css:

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

JavaScript + jQuery 1.11.0:

```
$("#output").pivotUI(
  $.pivotUtilities.tipsData, {
    rows: ["sex", "smoker"],
    cols: ["day", "time"],
    vals: ["tip", "total_bill"],
    aggregatorName: "Sum over Sum",
    rendererName: "Heatmap"
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Para preencher previamente os menus de filtro você pode utilizar a opção [inclusions](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters). O código fica assim:

```js
$("#output").pivotUI(
  $.pivotUtilities.tipsData, {
    rows: ["sex", "smoker"],
    cols: ["day", "time"],
    vals: ["tip", "total_bill"],
    aggregatorName: "Sum over Sum",
    rendererName: "Heatmap",
    inclusions: {
      sex:["Female"]
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.13.0/pivot.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.13.0/pivot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.6.0/tips_data.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Na hipótese dos valores do campo Sex serem gerados de forma aleatória, por exemplo: Male, Female, common, neuter. Como eu faria para utilizar o inclusion para deixar selecionado somente a primeira opção, sendo que essa ordem que mencionei no exemplo viria de forma aleatória?